# magento 2 custom module layout issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, magento2.2

Created Magento 2 custom module but the layout seems not showing anything.
It is supposed to show some output but it is showing white blank screen in the page.

Please help

My URL 
http://localhost/PG2/helloworld/Index/Index

Folder Structure:
http://prntscr.com/g1t4sp

controller code

```
      <?php

        namespace Inchoo\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

        use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

        class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
        {
            protected $_resultPageFactory;

            public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
            {
                $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
                parent::__construct($context);
            }

            public function execute()
            {

                // echo "Hello ";

                $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
                return $resultPage;
            }
        }
```

routes.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>

        <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
            <router id="standard">
                <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
                    <module name="Inchoo_Helloworld" />
                </route>
            </router>
        </config>
```

module.xml code

```
            <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
                <module name="Inchoo_Helloworld" setup_version="1.0.0">
                </module>
            </config>
```

helloworld_Index_Index

```
        <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
            <body>
                <referenceContainer name="content">
                    <block class="Inchoo\Helloworld\Block\Helloworld" name="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml" />
                </referenceContainer>
            </body>
        </page>
```

block class file

```
        class Helloworld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
        {
            public function getHelloWorldTxt()
            {
                return 'Hello world!';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check my updated answer. I tested your code in my setup and found two little mistakes in your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code. You made simple file naming mistakes

**1) Rename `helloworld_Index_Index.xml` to `helloworld_index_index.xml`**
(make router name in lowercase)

2) Remove space before file name at `app/code/Inchoo/Helloworld/view/frontend/templates`
rename **'(space)helloworld.phtml' to 'helloworld.phtml'**

Now keep this code in `helloworld.phtml` to test your code

```
I am testing buddy 

<?php echo $this->getHelloWorldTxt(); ?></h1>
```

Now remove var/generation and flush cache and try it's working now.

Comment: Tried about code but no luck yet

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know if you have any issue

Comment: no luck might be some little issue. uploaded module code so you can check it   https://files.fm/u/79555ggb

Comment: @DanialButt Check my updated answer. I tested your code in my setup and found two little mistakes in your code :)

Comment: http://localhost/PG2/helloworld/Index/Index
http://localhost/PG2/helloworld
http://localhost/PG2/helloworld/index/index

Tried above urls and followed above steps but it  says 404

Comment: I tested your code in my setup. Please remove extra code from `helloworld.phtml`. i found that there are extra code there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63068/discussion-between-danial-butt-and-prince-patel).

Comment: Helped me and guided me.And after removing var folder / subfolders I loaded the site and it start working ..  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The page should load with a 404 error if there is an issue with the code, not a white page. If you place a `die('die');` into the controller's `execute()` method and then your block's `_prepareLayout()` method, you will see if they are being hit and there is a syntax error there. But your issue sounds like the localhost server is getting a 500 error, which points to your local system.

Looking over the code above, i don't see any issues (except that you use `helloworld_Index_Index` and not `helloworld_index_index` but in the dir path you show, the file is named correctly). Also, you should be able to hit the controller with just `http://localhost/PG2/helloworld`, the index is redundant, but using it shouldn't create issues.

----UPDATE----

try changing your block class to this

```
class Helloworld extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    function _prepareLayout(){}
}
```

Comment: By putting die('die');  in controller I can see the die without any issue.

Comment: what is in your block class file? if it sees the controller, then the next file in the chain "should" be the layout xml. That is calling your block and setting your template. Try setting die statements in all of those and see where that fails, it will tell you which file has the error.

Comment: oh, and what exact version of m2 are you running?

Comment: This is what I can see http://prntscr.com/g2242v  using url http://localhost/PG2/helloworld/Index/Index

Comment: I am using 2.1.7

Comment: block class file updated please take a look

Comment: i updated my answer with what you can try with your block class